# how to configure apache mod_rewrite for web services

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, post, url-rewriting

I'm new to Apache mod_rewrite but I was able to get it to work for simple URL translation for static pages accessed using the GET method.
I'm having trouble to get the URL translation to work for web services though. Basically all I want is to redirect the request from Apache to tomcat that runs under  `8093` . I tried:

```
RewriteRule myproject/myservices/myService/(.*) http://www.localhost:8093/myproject/myservices/myService/$1
```

But I get a "The document has moved here" response. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your request is only rewritten, but not proxied. You could try to append `[P]` at the end or look into mod_proxy: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: That was it, thanks! I had to add ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse and it seems to work.